# Is it possible to apply color gradient to geom_smooth with ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to apply the scale colour gradient also to the smooth line.
At the moment the code below set the color fix to red.

```
library(ggplot2)
a <- data.frame(year = 1:100, values = sin(1:100)*1000 + runif(100))
ggplot(a, aes(x = year, y = values, color = values )) + geom_line(size = 2)  +
scale_colour_gradient2(
  low = "blue",
  mid = "white" ,
  high = "red",
  midpoint = 10
 )+
geom_smooth(
 data = a,
 aes(x = year, y = values),
 color = "red",
 size = 2
 )
```

[image]

But when I set `color = values` it doesn't work. Instead it takes the default blue.

```
geom_smooth(
 data = a,
 aes(x = year, y = values, color = values),
 size = 2
 )
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `geom_smooth(aes(color=..y..))` to add a color aesthetic to `geom_smooth`. `..y..` is the vector of y-values internally calculated by `geom_smooth` to create the regression curve. In general, when you want to add an aesthetic to a summary value that's calculated internally, you need to map the aesthetic to that internal value. Here, the internal value is the `..y..` value of the smoothing function. In other cases it might be `..count..` for histograms or bar plots, or `..density..` for density plots.

Here's an example using your data. Note that I've tweaked a few of the plot parameters for illustration.

```
set.seed(48)
a <- data.frame(year = 1:100, values = sin(1:100)*1000 + runif(100))

ggplot(a, aes(x = year, y = values, color = values )) + 
  geom_line(size = 0.5)  +
  geom_smooth(aes(color=..y..), size=1.5, se=FALSE) +
  scale_colour_gradient2(low = "blue", mid = "yellow" , high = "red", 
                         midpoint=10) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Note that the color of the regression line does not change much because its y-values span a small range relative to the data. Here's another example with fake data that generates a more wide-ranging regression curve.

```
set.seed(1938)
a2 <- data.frame(year = seq(0,100,length.out=1000), values = cumsum(rnorm(1000)))

ggplot(a2, aes(x = year, y = values, color = values )) + 
  geom_line(size = 0.5)  +
  geom_smooth(aes(color=..y..), size=1.5, se=FALSE) +
  scale_colour_gradient2(low = "blue", mid = "yellow" , high = "red", 
                         midpoint=median(a2$values)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks  a lot. That is exactly what I am looking for.